# Error trying to delete database user account schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-accounts

I'm trying to delete a user's schema from a database and I'm getting the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Drop failed for Schema 'ext_owner'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.4035.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Drop+Schema&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Cannot drop schema 'ext_owner' because it is being referenced by object 'getroles'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3729)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4035&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3729&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

What is the getroles object?

How do I get rid of the reference so I can remove the old user account?

Comment: What's the command that's causing this error? Also, each user has their own schema?! Surely I misunderstand.

Comment: I'm trying to delete the user and to do that it asks me if I also want to delete the schema. All I am doing to get this is right click on user, click delete.

Comment: You should become familiar with the DDL commands used to process such operations.  All the GUI does is hide this information from you, and make it harder for you to decipher what is going wrong.  Most dialogs in SSMS will allow you to click a script button at the top, and this is a quick way to learn the DDL for things you might normally rely on the GUI for (and should yield more insight on what is happening when you get these error messages).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE name = 'getroles' 
AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('ext_owner');
```

Then do:

```
DROP <object type> ext_owner.getroles;
```

--or

```
ALTER SCHEMA <some other schema> TRANSFER ext_owner.getroles;
```

You will likely have to repeat this a bunch of times.  You can't drop a schema that is not empty.

Comment: Nothing shows up when I execute the statment.  I get cannot drop schema 'bob222' because it is being referenced by object 'LanguagePackImport'

Answer (score 2):

You can query the [system table `sys.objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) to try to find more information on what getroles might be.

Try

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE '%getroles%'
```

This should give you some information on what the object is.  At that point you can either drop it or decide to change the schema so that it's no longer being referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'getroles'
```

My guess is that it is a function or stored procedure which that user created under their own schema (possibly accidentally. Drop it (if it's not being used) and you should be good to go.